# Erro de Comunicação Serial ttyS0

Tags: c, serial, raspberry-pi, pic, microcontrolador

Estou utilizando uma comunicação serial TTL via terminal com um Orange Pi One e um PIC16F628A. O programa que está no microcontrolador é simples: se caso receber o caractere '1' põe um bit em nível lógico alto, assim ligando o LED e ao receber o caractere '0' põe um bit em nível baixo e em ambos estados dará o feedback "Led aceso\n\r" e "Led apagado\n\r", respectivamente, e necessito para futuras aplicações. Estive usando os terminais Putty e o Minicom para a comunicação e tive exatamente o que eu queria. Porém quando criei um programa utilizando a serial com a API termios em C para o Mini PC. O programa abre a porta serial envia o caractere '1' e logo se fecha, em questão super simples... porém por algum motivo, o LED acende e após tempo indefinido (durando milissegundos ou até alguns minutos) se apaga, acontecendo **somente** no programa que criei, e parece que algum processo, do Ubuntu ARM ou da API em questão está jogando algum lixo para a serial. Estou há uma semana tentando entender o que está acontecendo e corrigir.

**Funcionando corretamente:**
[image: Usando o Minicom 2.7 com o Putty SSH e funcionando corretamente]
**Funcionando erroneamente:**
[image: Usando o Minicom 2.7 com o Putty SSH e com tabulação]

Essa tal *tabulação* mostrada no minicom aconteceu logo que o programa foi criado e executo em seguida o minicom para observar o que aconteceu. Toda vez que aparece essa tabulação, ocorre esse problema descrito acima.

Procurei diversos exemplos e teoria sobre como funciona mas o erro sempre permanece. Este é o link que peguei o código: raspberry-projects .com/pi/programming-in-c/uart-serial-port/using-the-uart

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>    //write
#include<string.h> //strcat
#include<fcntl.h> //flags
#include<termios.h>



//Declara variavel
int uart0_filestream = -1;


int main() 
{

//Abrindo a UART
//Flag O_RDWR permite que tenha uma conexao de envio e recebimento de dados
//O_NONBLOCK == O_NDelay modo nonblocking ativo
uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (uart0_filestream == -1)
{
    printf("Erro: Nao foi possivel abrir a porta serial. Verifique se ha alguma outra aplicacao usando-a.\n");
}

//Atribui flags
struct termios options;
tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD; //Atribui o baut rate
options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
options.c_oflag = 0;
options.c_lflag = 0;

tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);


unsigned char tx_buffer[20];
unsigned char *p_tx_buffer;

p_tx_buffer = &tx_buffer[0];
*p_tx_buffer++ = '1';
*p_tx_buffer++ = 10;
*p_tx_buffer++ = 13;

if (uart0_filestream != -1)
{
    printf("%c\n", tx_buffer[0]);
    int count = write(uart0_filestream, &tx_buffer[0], (p_tx_buffer - &tx_buffer[0]));
    //Filestream, bytes to write, number of bytes to write
    if (count < 0)
    {
        printf("UART TX error\n");
    }
}

close(uart0_filestream);
return 0; 
}
```